# Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’ and CORS request did not succeed

Tags: api, http, django-rest-framework, cors

Im trying to get api-data in angularjs using  django application. when i  try  to access api i get error-  **Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’ and CORS request did not succeed** . API is hosted in seperate django app.

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Bigflow.Core',

    'rest_framework',
    'Bigflow.API',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders'
    ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


 CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  # i teried false using CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8001',
)
    CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True # i tried both false and true
```

my js

```
 this.api = function () {
 var response =    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/Schedule_Master?Entity_gid=1&Action=FOLLOWUP_REASON&Schedule_Type_gid=1",{headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Token 7111*******************',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'

    }})
    return response;
    }
```

I had tried many solution from stackoverflow. I cant able to solve my problem ,OR do I want to change any config in my api hosted server(Django app). Please guide me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This error should be about the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` setting.

The `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`  will surely cause the problem.(Check the following link)

So except `localhost:8001`, try to whitelist `http://127.0.0.1:8001`as well, which may solve this problem. The browser treats `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` as different domains.

[Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials)

> The CORS request was attempted with the credentials flag set, but the server is configured using the wildcard ("*") as the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin, which doesn't allow the use of credentials.
>
> To correct this problem on the client side, simply ensure that the credentials flag's value is false when issuing your CORS request.
>
> If the request is being issued using XMLHttpRequest, make sure you're not setting withCredentials to true.
>
> If using Server-sent events, make sure EventSource.withCredentials is false (it's the default value).
>
> If using the Fetch API, make sure Request.credentials is "omit".
>
> If, instead, you need to adjust the server's behavior, you'll need to change the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin to grant access to the origin from which the client is loaded.